# Matlab Not Returning Orthonormal Matrix of Eigenvectors

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvector, eigenvalue

When I try to find the eigen-decomposition of a matrix in Matlab that has a repeated eigenvalue but is NOT defective, it is not returning an orthonormal matrix of eignevectors. For example:

```
k = 5;
repeats = 1;

% First generate a random matrix of eignevectors that is orthonormal
V = orth(rand(k));

% Now generate a vector of eigenvalues with the given number of repeats
D = rand(k,1);
for i = 1:repeats
    % Put one random value into another (note this sometimes will result in
    % less than the given number of repeats if we ever input the same
    % number)
    D(ceil(k*rand())) = D(ceil(k*rand()));
end

A = V'*diag(D)*V;

% Now test the eignevector matrix of A
[V_A, D_A] = eig(A);

disp(V_A*V_A' - eye(k))
```

I am finding that my matrix of eigenvectors `V_A` is not orthogonal i.e. `V_A*V_A'` is not equalling the identity matrix (taking into account rounding errors).

I was under the impression that if my matrix was real and symmetric then Matlab would return an orthogonal matrix of eigenvectors, so what is the issue here?

Comment: Are you sure you've taken rounding errors into account? Several runs of your code produces an error of `< 1e-15` for `V_A*V_A' - eye(k)`.

Comment: `V*V'-eye(5)<1e-15` is true, every time. As @IKavanagh said, sometimes your last line is `~1e-2`, sometimes it's `~1e-15`. I think that is because what you are doing to `D`.

Comment: Hi guys, yep I've taken rounding errors into account. It is only sometimes `~1e-15`. It is most often `~1e-2` which is too large. Have a look at `V_A*V_A'`, it is clearly not orthogonal in most cases. What I've done to `D` I don't think should matter, it is just allowing me to choose what eigenvalues I want.

Comment: Yes Adriaan, `V*V'-eye(5)<1e-15` is true everytime but not `V_A*V_A'-eye(5)<1e-15`, this is what I do not understand.

Comment: You need to check `V_A'*V_A`. Numerically you asked for the right eigenvectors. They should be equal but they are hardly equal. And orthogonal `!=` orthonormal. `V_A` are not necessarily orthonormal.

Comment: To be clear, the elements are on the order of `1E-2` because `V_A*V_A'` **is not an inner-product of the eigenvectors**; `V_A'*V_A` is.  Using that formula with the given code displays three epsilon-zero columns and two non-epsilon-zero columns due to the degeneracy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems to be a numerical precision issue.

The eigenvectors of a real symmetric matrix [are orthogonal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82467/eigenvectors-of-real-symmetric-matrices-are-orthogonal). But your input matrix `A` is not exactly symmetric. The differences are on the order of `eps`, as expected from numerical errors.

```
>> A-A.'
ans =
   1.0e-16 *
         0   -0.2082   -0.2776         0    0.1388
    0.2082         0         0   -0.1388         0
    0.2776         0         0   -0.2776         0
         0    0.1388    0.2776         0   -0.5551
   -0.1388         0         0    0.5551         0
```

If you force `A` to be *exactly* symmetric you'll get an orthogonal `V_A`, up to numerical errrors on the order of `eps`:

```
>> A = (A+A.')/2;
>> A-A.'
ans =
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
>> [V_A, D_A] = eig(A);
>> disp(V_A*V_A' - eye(k))
   1.0e-15 *
   -0.3331    0.2220    0.0755    0.1804         0
    0.2220   -0.2220    0.0572   -0.1665    0.1110
    0.0755    0.0572   -0.8882   -0.0590   -0.0763
    0.1804   -0.1665   -0.0590         0   -0.0555
         0    0.1110   -0.0763   -0.0555         0
```

Still, it's surprising that so wildly different results are obtained for `V_A` when `A` is symmetric and when `A` is *nearly* symmetric. This is my bet as to what's happening: as [noted by @ArturoMagidin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82467/eigenvectors-of-real-symmetric-matrices-are-orthogonal#comment194882_82467),

> (1) Eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix must be orthogonal to each other. Eigenvectors corresponding to the same eigenvalue need not be orthogonal to each other.
>
> (2) However, since every subspace has an orthonormal basis,you can find orthonormal bases for each eigenspace, so you can find an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors.

Matlab is probably taking route (2) (thus forcing `V_a` to be orthogonal) only if `A` is symmetric. For `A` not exactly symmetric it probably takes route (1) and gives you a basis of each subspace, but not necessarily with orthogonal vectors.

Comment: Great, I'm surprised that a difference that small in the 'symmetricness' of A  could have such a knock on effect.

Comment: @rwolst I've just edited my answer with a possible explanation

Comment: I think you're right with the explanation. If you don't force `A` to be exactly symmetric and look instead at `V_A'*V_A`, you will notice the leading diagonal is all `1` and the only off-diagonal elements not equal to `0` are those corresponding to the indices of the repeated eigenvectors in the `D` vector.

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvectors of a real matrix will be orthogonal if and only if AA'=A'A and eigenvalues are distinct. If eigenvalues are not distinct, MATLAB chooses an orthogonal system of vectors. In the above example, AA'~=A'A. Besides, you have to consider round off and numerical errors.